# live update a value on change with jquery

Tags: jquery, text, live

I have a span which contains the number of a element(in this case it counts the number of li elements in a list), these list items can be deleted so the number will change, how can i live update the number everytime the list gets changed?

This is the code that i use to count the list items

```
    var getTotal = jQuery('#ul li').length;
    $(".gettotal").text(getTotal);
```

I have looked on google but i didn't find anything.

Comment: Why not run this code (or add it in a function) every time a list item is deleted? That way, the number of `li` will be updated as you delete from the `ul`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are your li elements created or deleted?  You'll want to trigger a count update on that event.  You can utilize jQuery's ability to create/trigger custom events with [bind](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) and [trigger](http://api.jquery.com/trigger).

```
$('#ul').bind('li_deleted', function()
{
    $('.gettotal').text( $('#ul li').length );
});

//and every time an li is deleted..
$('#ul').trigger('li_deleted');
```

Another (and not so good) option is to run a timer on the page, and check if the # of list elements changes - but that's going to be very resource intensive, i wouldn't do it unless it was a last resort.

Comment: Thanks, i have tried this but it does count all of the list items but it doesn't update the number if i delete one.

Comment: if you delete one, you have to fire the event again, i don't know the context of your code so i don't know how they're being deleted - otherwise i'd give you a more illustrative example for your situation.

Comment: Well i use this to delete the items    
  jQuery('.ph-delete').click(function(){
   $(this).parent('li').slideUp(200,function(){
    $(this).remove()
   });
  });

Comment: so, right after `$(this).remove()` do `$('#ul').trigger('li_deleted');`

Comment: Ah, now it works, i now understand the trigger, it has to run true an event. Thanks for the simple solution!!!

Comment: the length in the trigger should be length -1, otherwise it will skipp the first trigger...and you will get a wrong value

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how often your list length changes, you may want to have a look at the Data-Link plugin for jQuery.

http://api.jquery.com/category/plugins/data-link